# Laravel - How to retrieve from child records inside a parent array?

Tags: php, laravel, parent-child

vehicles (Parent of car_details)

id - some_column1

1  - some_value

2  - some_value

...

cars (Parent of car_details):

id - some_column2

1  -     Benz

2  -     BMW

...

car_details (Child):

id - vehicle_id - car_id - some_column3

1  -     1      -    1   -  some_value

2  -     1      -    1   -  some_value

3  -     1      -    2   -  some_value

4  -     1      -    2   -  some_value

```
class Vehicle extends Model {
    public function carDetails() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CarDetail');
    }
}

class CarController extends Controller {
    $carDetails = Vehicle::with('carDetails')->first();
}
```

Now in my blade view I want to iterate over the cars and its child's details separately:

```
First Car:
@foreach($carDetails as $carDetail)
    <ul>
        <li>Car: {{$carDetail->car->some_column2}}</li>
        <li>Car Detail: {{$carDetail->some_column3}}</li>
    </ul>
@endforeach
Second Car:
@foreach($carDetails as $carDetail)
    <ul>
        <li>Car: {{$carDetail->car->some_column2}}</li>
        <li>Car Detail: {{$carDetail->some_column3}}</li>
    </ul>
@endforeach
//So on...
```

The problem is that the car details are showing continuously however I want to separate First Car details from Second details and the cars showing after that.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your desired result? What does it mean they "are showing continuously"?

Comment: It means I want it to be shown like car1 => speed - color | car2 => speed - color so on... However it is like this: car1 => speed - color - speed - color.

Answer (score 0):

I found it :)

I used `groupBy` not in SQL, but after fetching the data.

```
$vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);
$vehicle->cars = $vehicle->cars->groupBy('car_id');
```

Thanks anyway